# Worldpay payment not showing up in the checkout page

Tags: magento-enterprise, payment-gateway

We are using the Magento Enterprise Edition 1.14.2.1. It supports the Worldpay option out of the box. I enabled it on the admin payment methods configuration page. But I don't see a credit card option in the Payment Information tab on the checkout page. I only see Paypal, which is the other option we provide users. Is there some other configuration I'm missing? if not how would I debug this?